# Are paired matches in ranked data independent, if the original, unranked, continuous pairs are independent?

Tags: independence, paired-data, ranking, ranks, bernoulli-process

Let $(X, Y)$ be a randomly drawn sample of $n$ paired observations from a bivariate continuous population. It is clear that each pair is independent of the others, both pairwise and mutually. Let $R(X, Y)$ be the same data converted to ascending ranks without ties, e.g., the $i^{th}$ smallest value in $R(X)$ is replaced with $i$, same for $R(Y)$. Let $B$ be the binary sequence such that $b_i = 1$ if $R(x_i) = R(y_i)$, otherwise $b_i = 0$.

Am I correct that values in $B$ must be independent? In other words, may $B$ be modelled as a random draw of size $n$ from a Bernoulli distribution?

The simplest argument I can think of is that rank order is a property of both continuous values and ordinal values, so if the ranks are dependent, then the continuous pairs would also be dependent *through their rank order*. Likewise, "matchiness of rank order" is a property of paired ranks, and therefore of paired continuous data, so dependence of values in $B$ implies dependence of values in $(X, Y)$.

That said, this is for a response to a reviewer, and peer reviewers in my experience respond better to theorems, or citations thereof, than to mere logic. (And, I concede, my logic could be flawed!)

Edit: It also occurs to me that dependence is a question of whether variables' distributions are related, not their observed values, and it seems to me that the distribution of each $b_i$ is $Bern(p)$.

Comment: Suppose the first $n-1$ values of $B$ are $1:$ that implies the last value must be $1,$ too, proving the sequence is *not* independent.  So this line of inquiry is not going to rescue whatever claim the reviewer might be questioning.  But why do you need independence?

Comment: I see your point. Conversely, given a sequence of pairs of real numbers, if I add another independent pair to the sequence, the respective ranks of all (xi, yi)'s are all subject to change *depending on* the values in the new pair.

Comment: I need independence for Le Cam's theorem to apply to the sum of $B$. Specifically, $sum(B)\sim Pois(np)$, approximately and asymptotically, for $p = P(x_i = y_i)$. There are of course other theorems that weaken the independence condition, like Stein-Chen. But there are many kinds of dependence, presumably with different ways of converging to Poisson, so Le Cam would be a nice simplification. That said, my earlier draft used Monte Carlo sims to show rapid convergence to $Pois(np)$ with increasing $n$, in terms of $TVD$. I prefer the principled description, though.